# Change database password?

Tags: joomla-4.x, database

I am trying to change the Joomla database password. I cannot figure it out. If I change the password in the database first, then Joomla is unable to use it, because it no longer has access to the database, but if I change it in Joomla first, then it cannot be stored because the password is wrong.

This seems like it should be an extremely basic thing. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct method is to update database password first, either via your hosting control panel or the command line.

Then manually update the password in configuration.php either through the File Manager in your hosting control panel, or update it locally and then upload via FTP.

Comment: I have to test this tomorrow, because of reasons, but if this is true, I would consider it to be a very significant bug. Luckily, I own my own, so it's not a big worry for me, but being able to change passwords without going into GNU+Linux is fairly important, I would think.

Comment: Joomla has no authority to change database credentials and this is normally done through the hosting control panel. This is not a bug but a security feature!

Comment: Joomla has the authority ot change its own files? What is the purpose of the ability to change the password in the control panel if Joomla is not capable of doing so? If Joomla isn't capable, it should simply state how to do it.

Comment: I agree the solution proposed by Snaffle is correct. MYSQL requires a clear password. The site owner is responsible to keep his file system secure.